# Setting the value of css property to value of a html attribute

Tags: html, css

HTML example:

```
<div data-style-top="20%">Hi, I'm not so high right now.</div>
```

Here, I want the div with 'data-style-top' attribute which is set to '20%' to have a css property of `top:20%;` If the attribute value was 50% then top property should have the value '50%'.

Any ways to achieve this? Like:

```
div[data-style-top]:before {
 top: content(attr(data-style-top));
}
```

Sorry if I couldn't explain properly. I suck at explaining.

Comment: cannot with only css, with jquery `$('[data-style-top]').data('style-top`')

Comment: Do you want it to work for all data-style-XXX attributes?  So like if it had data-style-width="40px", it would also recognize that?  It's also possible with jQuery, though a bit more difficult than just top.

Comment: TIL using `attr()` value for another property than `content` is part of a CSS3 module (for now) but is unsupported (for now). Source: **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)** (edit: comment in bugzilla says it should work in IE9+. Can't test this today)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Beware! Browser support might be bad.*

In [*CSS Values and Units Module Level 3*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) (which is [currently](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/) a Candidate Recommendation), the syntax for [`attr()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/#attr) would be:

```
div[data-style-top] {
  top: attr(data-style-top %);
}
```

You could also provide a fallback value, if the `data-style-top` attribute doesn’t have a value:

```
div[data-style-top] {
  top: attr(data-style-top %, 10);
}
```

- `data-style-top` is the HTML attribute to be used
- `%` is the CSS type/unit to be used
- `10` is the fallback (= `10%`)

---

Note that `attr()` [is](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/#status) "at-risk and may be dropped during the CR period".

This week a new CR (2013-11-21) was published, which, for whatever reason, is [not yet](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20131121/) public, aside from the [Editor’s Draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/) namespace. `attr()` is still included, but again listed as "at-risk".

Answer (score -1):

Another solution here :

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zTv8s/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('before : ' + $("*[data-style-top]").attr("data-style-top")); // for demo : 20%
           $("*[data-style-top]").attr("data-style-top","50%");
    alert('after : ' + $("*[data-style-top]").attr("data-style-top")); // for demo : 50%

});
```

Variant with a for each and a specific id : http://jsfiddle.net/zTv8s/3/